# Cannot redeclare class JSONParserException

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

This is my code,

which always produce error  when `"new Entity\UserAds($array);"` is added

Entities are present in `"models\Entity\"` folder

```
use Entity\UserAds;

use Entity\Comment;

class postad extends CI_Controller {

    protected $view_data;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct ();

        $this->load->helper ( array (
                'form',
                'url' 
        ) );

        $this->load->library ( 'form_validation' );

        // view data



    }
    public function index() {

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->view_data ['content'] = 'contents/postads';
            $this->load->view ( 'templates/layout', $this->view_data );

        } else {
            $array = $this->input->post ();
            try {

                $ads =  UserAds::createFromPost($array );
                $this->em = $this->doctrine->em;
                //$repository = $this->em->getRepository ( 'Entity\User' );
                $this->em->persist ( $ads );
                $this->em->flush ();
                $this->session->set_flashdata ( 'err_msg', "" );

                $this->log ( "create_post() created new ads." );
                $this->view_data['count']=$this->input->post('count');
                $this->view_data ['result'] = $ads;
                $adid=$ads->getId();
                $ads->getImages();



                $this->session->set_userdata('id',$adid);
                $this->load->model("emailmodel");
                $this->emailmodel->send_notification($ads->getEmail(),$adid,$ads->getTitle());

                if($this->session->userdata("username")==""){

                /*new block added  from  */ 
                    $array = array ();
                    $name=$array ['name'] = $ads->getName();
                    $mobile=$array ['mobile'] = $ads->getMobile();
                    $array ['email'] =$ads->getEmail();
                    $array ['password'] = '12345';
                    $array ['dob'] = DateTime::createFromFormat ( "d/m/Y", '');
                    $array ['everified'] = 0;
                    $array ['mverified'] = 0;
                    $array ['devicetype'] = 0;
                    $array ['usertype'] = 0;

                    $user = new Entity\User ( $array );
                    $this->em->persist ( $user );
                    $this->em->flush ();  //till this

                    $this->load->model ( 'homemodel' );
                    $randstr = $this->homemodel->rand_string ( $name, $mobile );
                    $this->load->model ( 'emailmodel' );
                    $email =$ads->getEmail();
                    $randstr = $this->emailmodel->getmailcode ( $email );
                    $this->emailmodel->sendVerificatinEmail ( $email, $randstr );


                }

                $this->view_data ['content'] = 'contents/adcreated';
                $this->load->view ( 'templates/layout', $this->view_data );
            } catch ( Exception $e ) {

                $this->error ( "createAds(): creation faield." . $e->getMessage () );
                $this->session->set_flashdata ( 'err_msg', "Failed to post ad" . $e->getMessage () );
                $this->view_data ['content'] = 'contents/postads';
                $this->load->view ( 'templates/layout', $this->view_data );
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my error message:

> Cannot redeclare class JSONParserException in C:\wamp\www\rah\application\core\JSONParserException.php on line 12

Comment: Please post the full error message and the code which corresponds to the error.

Comment: fixed code formatting

Comment: i have solved this problem by replacing code 'include'  with  'include_once'